# Annotated 9x9 Go Games

Tags: go

I've recently started playing Go and I would like to study some annotated 9x9 games, but can't seem to find anything. Does anyone know where I could find such games? If it's free that would be even better.

Comment: http://www.usgo.org/learn-overview#CommentedBeginners has four games

Comment: Or lots of commented games played by normal players (not professional players): http://gtl.xmp.net/reviews/of_smallboards

Comment: @ChingChong great answer

Answer (score 3):

There is not much written about 9x9 Go games, but you can find a few videos about them on Youtube.  I would recommend the following series of videos 'Crazy Nines', by Go content creator xhu98:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGTqST4O93ERWgQkCroFSCg4UiOgmL4Mq

The series features Dan level amateur players discussing 9x9 strategy.  This is the best 9x9 analysis I have been able to find.